# How could I connect Windows C#, Android and Browser to one database using sockets. (Chat Application)

Tags: c#, android, sockets, browser

I am making a chat application for Windows Desktop (C#), Android (Java) and Browser.
What would be the best way to make sure that in all 3 clients user sends and receives messages instantly?
I mean is there ONE service that could provide this all?
So far I found GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) and WebSockets, however it seems that GCM is same as WebSockets except it's all automated (I think).

I mean I could call refresh in all clients every second but that seems like a huge resource waste. 
Browsr could use Ajax I guess to get newest chat messages.

Android could use GCM.

But what can Windows use? I've never really properly made Windows software.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any doubt, you should use a **WebSocket**. The use of Ajax for a service like chat could a terrible decision because you will have to be asking the server everytime you want to know if there are new messages, or waiting for a timer to execute this request.

For browser (for instance python or Java, but I guess in all technologies) there should be libraries which could help you.

For Android, I've worked with Java Websocket Android and it worked like a charm.

Websocket stablishes a bidirectional connection (we could call ir a private channel always open) between all clients (in your case, between browser, Android app and Windows) and the server and everyone communicates throught their connection.

C# must have its own library for that.

Please, take a look because I think it's a definetly better option.

I hope I could helpe you! Good luck!

Comment: Do I have to use Cloud server for WebSocket?

Comment: You should. A server gives you many services you will need (persistence, synchronization, users in the chat etc.) I've been developing an app which shows the same information in several devices, but the devices are synchronized by a server.

Comment: Can I use PHP Sockets? 
Also I don't have resources to rent cloud server, what framework should I use to host my own home server? (it's prototype, so doesn't really matter for now)

Comment: I suppose you can. In my case I developed client side (Android) and I established connections with a Python (Tornado) server. Websocket is a protocol, so every language must have its own implementation, and the community probably would develop libraries. If you know PHP, here you can see a mini tutorial: http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/05/chat-using-websocket-php-socket , but this is one among many... develop depending on your own ability and knowledge! Good luck with your task!

Comment: I just started looking into socketo.me
It's a PHP WebSocket Library which seems easy to use, and there also seems to be tutorials on how to connect to it with Android.

Comment: Go on! I'm not expert in PHP (I know almost anything.. :P) As I told you, good luck buddy